# Python Get a Dataset from other Dataframe with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe from another dataframe with two conditions. I want to create a new DataFrame called 'dt_train' from the old DataFrame called 'dt'.

I tried this code:

```
dt_train = dt.loc[dt['Cardhldr'] == 1 | dt['Cardhldr'] == 0]
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'Categorical'
```

The var named 'Cardhldr' is numerical, type int64.

How can I get that?

On the other hand, I want to get from de old DataFrame the values NaN's, and I tried this:

```
dt_test = dt.loc[dt['Cardhldr'] == NaN]
```

Getting this message error: name 'NaN' is not defined.

How can I solve all of this errors and get what I want..?

Thanks !! Best regards !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose your conditions by `( )` because `|` has [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) over `==`.

Use:

```
dt_train = dt.loc[(dt['Cardhldr'] == 1) | (dt['Cardhldr'] == 0)]

# or simply

dt_train = dt.loc[dt['Cardhldr'].isin([0, 1])]
```

You can't compare a number to `NaN` because `float('nan') == float('nan')` returns False. You have to use `isna`:

```
df_test = dt.loc[dt['Cardhldr'].isna()]  # or .notna()?
```

`NaN` is not a keyword, you have to create a variable for that:

```
NaN = float('nan')

# or use numpy

from numpy import nan as NaN
```